# change Terminal Background and Foreground Color

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am new Ubuntu user. 
I would to change the background color and foreground color of terminal (permanently). 
Is there any app or command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually!

You just have to open a terminal window. Then, right click on it and 'Profile'>'Profile Preferences'>'Colors'. Here you can customize to your heart's content.